# Naming conventions required for DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've seen the official [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495.aspx) documentation about `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`, however, it doesn't seem to indicate this required naming convention hinted by [this question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495.aspx)

I know the code has to be something like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HandleKeyPressEventProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HandleKeyPressEvent",
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(MyDataGrid),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
public static bool GetHandleKeyPressEvent(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty);
}
public static void SetHandleKeyPressEvent(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty, value);
}
```

In this case is the Get and Set methods required to keep that name? Is the attached property required to end in "Property"? Also, could I make my code something like this instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HandleKeyPressEventProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FooEvent", //change registered name
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(MyDataGrid),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
public static bool GetHandleKeyPressEvent(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty);
}
public static void SetHandleKeyPressEvent(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(HandleKeyPressEventProperty, value);
}
```

Can anyone clear up this "magic" naming scheme and what kind of standard I have to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if everything in there is required, but that is also the format I use and I think this is what I see everywhere. If you change anything in there, even if it still works - you will introduce chaos and anarchy! :)

This is a version from [my code snippets](http://bit.ly/xyzzersnippets), based on revised [Dr. WPF's snippets](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/17/my-wpf-code-snippets/):

```
#region IsDirty
/// <summary>
/// IsDirty Attached Dependency Property
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDirtyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsDirty",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(AnimationHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsDirtyChanged));

/// <summary>
/// Gets the IsDirty property. This dependency property 
/// indicates blah blah blah.
/// </summary>
public static bool GetIsDirty(DependencyObject d)
{
    return (bool)d.GetValue(IsDirtyProperty);
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the IsDirty property. This dependency property 
/// indicates blah blah blah.
/// </summary>
public static void SetIsDirty(DependencyObject d, bool value)
{
    d.SetValue(IsDirtyProperty, value);
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles changes to the IsDirty property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="d">
/// The <see cref="DependencyObject"/> on which
/// the property has changed value.
/// </param>
/// <param name="e">
/// Event data that is issued by any event that
/// tracks changes to the effective value of this property.
/// </param>
private static void OnIsDirtyChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool oldIsDirty = (bool)e.OldValue;
    bool newIsDirty = (bool)d.GetValue(IsDirtyProperty);
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Well, from what I can tell, changing something like `GetIsDirty` to `GetIsDirtyFoo` will cause the attached property to stop working... So, a magical naming scheme that's not really documented as such

Comment: Not sure if it is not documented. Having started learning XAML development 4 years ago with ["WPF Unleashed"](http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-ebook/dp/B003UBAYXE/ref=sr_1_1_title_1_kin?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1356713126&sr=1-1&keywords=wpf+4.0+unleashed) by Adam Nathan - I remember reading something about various required naming conventions there, so it must be documented somewhere. Unless it's only documented for WPF and not for WinRT/XAML yet.

Comment: Looking at the [Custom attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965327.aspx) article it does say: "This topic explains how to implement an attached property as a dependency property and **how to define the accessor convention that is necessary for your attached property to be usable in XAML**."

Comment: Also, you might want to know the current limitations of using these in WinRT/XAML. AFAIK [(1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965327.aspx) - "_An existing limitation of the Windows Runtime XAML implementation is that you cannot animate your custom attached property._" and [(2)](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/402715) - animations are not supported for enum type dependency properties.

Comment: That "Custom attached proprties" article should fully document the naming requirements.  I don't see anything missing; it says "The property name must match the attached property name you specify as the RegisterAttached name parameter, with the string 'Property' added to the end" and "you must also provide static GetPropertyName and SetPropertyName methods as accessors for the attached property."  If there is something missing, let me know and I can hunt down the answer and get the documentation fixed.